# Click even it not working on Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Hi I am trying to make drag drop feature in JS, It works fine in Firefox, but it doesn't work on chrome. I Think it is something to do with `Event Deligation`, I am attaching the [link](http://codepen.io/iiison/pen/myMqEJ) of my code base. Following are the steps to reproduce the problem:

- Create a new Task
- Drag it to another column
- Now click on Edit or Delete Icon(E and D in circle).

Following are the Code highlights(Code is a bit bigger You can check it on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/iiison/pen/myMqEJ)):

JS:

```
$(function(){
    function init(){    
        var     mouseX = 0,     // Mouse Position
            mouseY = 0,

            elmX     = 0,       // Element Position 
            elmY     = 0,

            pillers    = $('.pillers'), // Task Container
            pillerWidth = $('.pillers:nth-child(1)').width(), // Taks Container width
            currentElm;  // Current Element
        
        /* When Left Mouse Button is Pressed */
        $('.dragable').on('mousedown', function(e){
            var temp;
            $(this).addClass('rel');

            mouseX = e.clientX;     // Current Mouse Position and Store it to global variables
            mouseY = e.clientY;

            temp = +($(this).css('left').slice(0, -2));     // Get Element Position and if it not a number then change it to 0
            elmX = null || isNaN(temp) ? 0 : temp;

            temp = +($(this).css('top').slice(0, -2));
            elmY = null || isNaN(temp) ? 0 : temp;
            
            $(this).css({'z-index':'9999'});    // Increase the Z-Index of the Element so that it wont be overlapped by other element.

            currentElm = $(this);       // set the current value so that it could be use by mouse move

            /* Some Hack for not let heighlight the data(Copied from net)  */
            document.body.focus();
            document.onselectstart = function () { return false; }; 
            $(this).ondragstart = function() { return false; }; 
            return false;
        }).on('mouseup',function(e){        // This will be fired when Mouse Button release back
            if(currentElm !== null){
                
                currentElm.removeClass('rel').prependTo('.arrived .tasks').css({    // Resetting the Position Object
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0
                });
                currentElm.css({'z-index' : '1'});  // Set Z-Index back to normal value.
                currentElm = null;      // Finally Set the Current Element to null so that it won't get dragged any more
            }
        }).on("mousemove", function(e){     // Mouse Move Event .. This is the main part, It will reposition the element with mouse pointer
            if(currentElm !== undefined && currentElm !== null){
                currentElm.addClass('draged').css({         // This sets the position of div element
                    left : (elmX + e.clientX - mouseX)+'px',
                    top : (elmY + e.clientY - mouseY)+'px'
                });

                /* Set Appropriate Class to Piller to Which The Element is going to be added */
                if( e.clientX >= $('.pillers:nth-child(1)').offset().left && e.clientX < ($('.pillers:nth-child(1)').offset().left+pillerWidth) && e.clientY < $('.pillers:nth-child(1)').outerHeight()){
                    $('.pillers:nth-child(1)').addClass('arrived').siblings('.pillers').removeClass('arrived');
                }else if(e.clientX >= $('.pillers:nth-child(2)').offset().left && e.clientX < ($('.pillers:nth-child(2)').offset().left+pillerWidth) && e.clientY < $('.pillers:nth-child(2)').outerHeight()){
                    $('.pillers:nth-child(2)').addClass('arrived').siblings('.pillers').removeClass('arrived');
                }else if(e.clientX >= $('.pillers:nth-child(3)').offset().left && e.clientX < ($('.pillers:nth-child(3)').offset().left+pillerWidth) && e.clientY < $('.pillers:nth-child(3)').outerHeight()){
                    $('.pillers:nth-child(3)').addClass('arrived').siblings('.pillers').removeClass('arrived');
                }else if(e.clientX >= $('.pillers:nth-child(4)').offset().left && e.clientX < ($('.pillers:nth-child(4)').offset().left+pillerWidth) && e.clientY < $('.pillers:nth-child(4)').outerHeight()){
                    $('.pillers:nth-child(4)').addClass('arrived').siblings('.pillers').removeClass('arrived');
                }
            }
        });

        $('a.remove').on('click',function(){
            console.log('hey')
            $(this).parents('.dragable').remove();
        });

        $('.add_task_button').on('click',function () {
            var place= $(this).closest('.create_task_box'),
                titl=place.find('input#title').val(),
                disc=place.find('textarea#discription').val(),
                time = new Date(),
                format = time.toLocaleDateString();


            if(titl || disc){
                var val = $('.temp').clone(true).removeClass('temp hide').insertBefore(place);
                val.find('#TaskHeading').val(titl).end().find('#task-discription').text(disc).end().find('.time').text(format).css({
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0
                });
            }
            $('input#title, textarea#discription').val('');
        });
        $(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){
            e.stopPropagation();

            if($(this).is('.done')){
                $(this).removeClass('done');

                $(this).closest('.task-unit').addClass('dragable').find('input, textarea').attr('readonly', 'readonly').addClass('readonly');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('done');
                var task = $(this).closest('.dragable');

                task.removeClass('dragable').find('input, textarea').removeAttr('readonly').removeClass('readonly');
            }
        });
    }

    init();
});
```

I am not mentioning the HTML and CSS part here because it will take a lot of space.. You can see full code [Here on Codepen](http://codepen.io/iiison/pen/myMqEJ).

Let me know if anything else required.

Comment: So.. nobody is answering that question....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have an object (parent) with a `mousedown` event and inside it, another object (children) with a `click` event. It seems that in Chrome, the first event (mousedown) is capturing the click over the buttons.

As a workaround, you can do this:

- have a function for the `mousedown` event on the parent element.
- unbind the `mousedown` event when the user does a `mouseover` event on the children.
- bind again the function to the parent when the user does a `mouseout` off the parent.

As an example:

```js
$(".theparent").on("mousedown",function(){
    doThings();
});
$(".thechildren").on("click",function(){
    alert("Child");
});
$(".thechildren").on("mouseover",function(){    
    $(this).closest(".theparent").off("mousedown");    
    console.log("Off");
});

$(".thechildren").on("mouseout",function(){
    $(this).closest(".theparent").on("mousedown",doThings);
    console.log("on");
});

function doThings(){
  alert("Parent");   
}
```

```css
.theparent{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#3a3a3a;
    position:absolute;
}
.thechildren{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    left:50px;
    top:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="theparent">
    <div class="thechildren">Child</div>
</div>
```

[**See it working on fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6v1goucc/).